# Video signal on HTML page

Tags: html, flash, video, activex, webcam

I've to show a video source (WebCam or Video Grabber) in an HTML page. 
I have NO need to stream or capture the signal, but I need only to overlay the video on the HTML page, since the PC that has to show the signal it the same that receive it.

I tried the following, but all of them are too jerkily or with a sort of "interlaced" view:

- HTML5 and Chrome Canary
- Adobe Flash with Camera.getCamera
- VideoCapX (an ActiveX recorder)
- Java applet

I think that for obtain the smoothness I've to find an element that handle the "overlay" method.
Remember that I can install what I want on this PC since I don't have to stream the signal.

Thank you very much in advance.